# Allow users access to an add-in but no the site that host it SP Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I have a team site which have a lot of list and libraries, also I've an add-in that use all that data and show results with it, Is there a way in which I can allow the users to only see the add-in and they can't see the site? I mean, if they try to access the site which host the app, is it possible they get access denied or something like that? if so, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to do this via the permission system, but sadly you can't create a permission level where you can't view but still edit items in lists and libraries, the system forces you to check view if you check edit.

I myself settled with editing the landing page to suggest the user to click a link to launch the add-in. I wish there was a way to specify landing page like add-in, so users entering the site would end up loading it.